# How to check current of Peltier module?

Tags: current, multimeter, peltier

[image]

I recently ordered this Peltier module so that I can make a thermoelectric generator (using heat to create some voltage.)

How can I measure the current produced using a multimeter?

I'm relatively new to electronics and I recently got my first multimeter.  When I watched a video, it stated that you need to make the multimeter part of the circuit otherwise the fuse will blow. I'm not really sure how to do this as there are just two wires coming off of the module with nothing else attached and I don't want to fry my multimeter from directly putting the probes onto the wires. What should I do?

Comment: You need to learn how to use a multimeter and it's a bit basic for this site as it involves taking you through several convoluted scenarios so that you can acquire the knowledge. So, unfortunately this question will probably get closed with the reason "needs more focus" which can also mean "too broad" i.e. any answer is too convoluted and is not suitable for this site.

Comment: Hint: look for *current measurement multimeter* on the internet, and avoid videos. Rather, articles with "boring" graphics. Things that are colorful or entertainingly narrated and moving are usually not very good (that's because they tend to be optimized for maximum page impressions rather than technical correctness).

Comment: I looked at multiple sources online and they all too say that same thing which is to interrupt the flow of current and put the meter in between. Now this is easy to do with other circuits since you only need to disconnect one part of it but with my peltier module there are literally just two wires. Answer me how I disrupt my circuit that only has two wires?

Comment: you do not have a circuit ... you have an unconnected component (peltier module) .... what circuit are you connecting it to?

Comment: After talking to some people I realized that I didn't have a load that is needed for measuring current, originally I was asking how to measure the Peltier module without any load or rest of the circuit which is why I was confused. I think I can connect the probes directly to the wires though since the current produced is not high enough to blow the fuse but I might be wrong. If anyone can give some input to doing this it would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't blow a fuse connecting the Peltier to just the DMM. I'd look for a DMM with 20mA and 200mA ranges though.

Comment: Doesn't the dmm have a low resistance so when you connect the current it will short it?

Comment: I hope that you do realize that the amount of energy one can "harvest" using a peltier element is **very small**. Watch this video by Dave from the EEVBlog where he shows how (un)practical it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4OeOQtiW0w  As you appear to be very new to electronics it is easy for you to get sucked into projects that **appear cool** but are **completely unrealistic** and will only result in frustrations.